# Make YouTube Video Full Width and Fixed Height

Tags: html, css, youtube, height, width

I want to display a YouTube video full width and with a height of 700px.

Here's my embed code:

```
<iframe class="home_video_iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" 
 title="YouTube video player" width="100%" height="100%"
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3iboEi4GvQA
 autoplay=1&amp;color=white&amp;controls=0&amp;disablekb=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&am;
 loop=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=light&amp;wmode=
 transparent&amp;playlist=3iboEi4GvQA&amp"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use % for width as you did and use `height: 700px;` instead of `height: 100%;`

```
<iframe class="home_video_iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="100%" height="700px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3iboEi4GvQA?autoplay=1&amp;color=white&amp;controls=0&amp;disablekb=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;loop=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=light&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;playlist=3iboEi4GvQA&amp"></iframe>
```

But remember, you cannot force to resize exactly to your need as the video will stretch. Suppose you have 300px wide screen size and you forced to have `height: 700px;`. It will not work for youtube videos. They will resize itself to looks nice.

Comment: thanks for your reply but the problem is that I don't wanna see YouTube's black margins, want to have full width of the video itself without the black margins.

Comment: The black margin appears only in the top and bottom, not in left and right. Do you want to remove the black margin from top and bottom?

Comment: no, I need this only for wide screens that's why I have margin in left and right

Comment: I do not see any margins on right and left. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: You cannot have full `width` when you are limiting the height of the iframe. You will get full width if you increase the height to `160%` but that will be more than `1200px`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe class="home_video_iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="100%" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3iboEi4GvQA?autoplay=1&amp;color=white&amp;controls=0&amp;disablekb=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;loop=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=light&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;playlist=3iboEi4GvQA&amp"></iframe>
```

Where it says the height set it for example height="500px".

Answer (score -1):

The key to creating a responsive YouTube embed is with padding and a container element, which allows you to give it a fixed aspect ratio. You can also use this technique with most other iframe-based embeds, such as slideshows.

*Here is what a typical YouTube embed code looks like, with fixed width and height:*

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yCOY82UdFrw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

*It would be nice if we could just give it a 100% width, but it won't work as the height remains fixed. What you need to do is wrap it in a container like so (note the class names and removal of the width and height):*

```
<div class="container">
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yCOY82UdFrw" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="video"></iframe>
</div>
```

*And use the following CSS:*

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**How this works:** The container element is given a zero height and a percentage bottom padding. The percentage bottom padding is a percentage of the container width, so that gives it a fixed aspect ratio. But in order to get the iframe to show up inside the zero-height container, you need to make the container relative and the iframe absolute, positioned inside the div.